# Best practice for end to end testing whole systems

Tags: tdd, end-to-end

End to end testing means exercising an application from the outer boundaries to verify its behavior. This far I've only done written tests for a single executable artifact. How should I test systems made up of multiple artifacts that is deployed on different hosts?

I see two alternatives.

- The tests set up the whole system and exercise it from the very outer edges.
- Each artifact is end to end tested in isolation, relying on the test content to enforce the protocol between them.

Is there a clear case for only adhering to one of these, or are one of them preferred, or are they interchangeable? If interchangeable, then what are some advantages and disadvantages between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I think it depends on the context, I prefer the first alternative. Here are my random thoughts:

I like my tests to be as closely mapped to use cases as possible (BDD style) (with the disclaimer that I misuse the term use case). These use cases may span several applications and sub-systems.

Example: *A back office administrator can view a transaction made by a user from the public interface.*

Here, the back office admin interface and the public interface are different applications, but they are included in the same use case.

Mapping these thoughts to your problem where you have sub-systems deployed on different hosts, I would say it depends on how it is used, from the user/actor perspective. Do the use cases span several sub-systems?

Also, perhaps the fact that the system is deployed on several hosts isn't important to the tests. You could replace the inter-process communication with method calls in your tests and have the whole system within the same process during tests, reducing the complexity. Supplement this with tests that only verify the inter-process communication.

**Edit:**

I realise that I forgot to include *why* I prefer to test the whole system.

Your asset is features, that is, behaviour, while the code is a liability. Therefore you'd like to test the behaviour, not the code (BDD style).

If you are testing each sub-system separately you are testing the code, not the features. Why? When you divided your system into sub-systems you did so based on some technical reasons. When you learn more you might discover that the chosen seam is sub-optimal and would like to move some responsibility from one sub-system to another. And you would have to modify test and production code at the same time, leaving you without a safety net. That's a typical symptom of testing implementation details.

That said, these kind of tests are too blunt to test everything. So you need to have complementary tests for details as well, where necessary.

Comment: This resonates well with my understanding of TDD, thanks for the response Torbjörn.

Answer (score 1):

Testing each artifact end-to-end separately would be highly desiderable in *any case*.  This will ensure that every artifact is sound.

In addition, you might want to test a composition of artifacts.  That would catch problems in the interactions between artifacts.  I don't know about your situation, but one thing that is important to have is a test environment that is a copy of production.  Testing the system in the test environment is a very good idea.  You might also want to test the system in the production environment; this might be feasible or not.  For instance, if your system processes credit card payments, you may want to avoid test payments on the production system.

In any case, testing each system separately is imho more important than testing the composition.  Once you know that your artifacts are sound in isolation, catching interaction tests will be much easier.  If you only have the end-to-end test of the whole system, it's much more difficult to understand where is the error when the tests fail.

Comment: These are good observations, but it feel this apply more to legacy code where I start out with production code but no safety net. With TDD one also write unit tests which work hand in hand with end-to-end tests. There are always bugs, but then I write another unit test that guard against a recurrence of that bug.